# How to cancel vacuum process in AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Is there a way to cancel an automatic vacuum in rds postgresql? When running

- `select pg_cancel_backend(...);`
- `select pg_terminate_backend(...);`

with a user that has the rds_superuser role an error occurs:

- ERROR:  must be a superuser to cancel superuser query
- ERROR:  must be a superuser to terminate superuser process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rds_superuser` is not a superuser.

You should not cancel autovacuum, it is doing an important job for the integrity of your database. But unless it is an anti-wraparound autovacuum run, you can make it die with a conflicting lock:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '2s';
LOCK table_being_vacuumed IN SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE MODE;
ROLLBACK;
```

Normal autovacuum runs die if they block a user session for more than a minute. There is nothing you can do about anti-wraparound autovacuum runs.